# Formik 2.0.1 useFormikContext formik values undefined

Tags: formik

Using `useFormikContext` in `Formik 2.0.1`. Receiving `Cannot read property 'values' of undefined` when binding formik.values in the form.

Thanks in advance!...

[image: Edit react-router useFormikContext]

Comment: see my _answer_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define formik inside the InnerForm() like this:

```
const InnerForm = () => {
      const formik = useFormikContext<IPerson>()
    return (
      <form>
        <input name="id" value={formik.values.id} />
        <input name="name" value={formik.values.name} />
      </form>
    );
  };
```

Comment: What is `IPerson` supposed to be?