# Formik | error useFormikContext formik values undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I have the following code:

```
const {
     values,
     handleChange,
     setFieldValue,
     handleSubmit,
     isSubmitting,
     isValid 
} = useFormikContext();
```

And i have the formik form inside a const comp

```
const Body = () => {
 ...
 return(
 <Formik
   ....
   ....>
   {props=>{

     <Form>
       ... then some fields here... etc
       ...
       ...
     </Form>

    }}

 </Formik>
}
```

It gives me this **error**:

## TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'values' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.

I've also checked this question:
[Formik 2.0.1 useFormikContext formik values undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58669214/formik-2-0-1-useformikcontext-formik-values-undefined)

however it didnt work even writing useFormikContext() inside Body

Answer (score 34):

> This hook will only work if there is a parent Formik React Context from which it can pull from.

[Source](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext)

Make sure you are using `useFormikContext` in a descendant of `<Formik>` Something like this:

```
<Formik>
  <Form>
    <MyApp />
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

```
// MyApp.jsx

const MyApp = () => {
  const formik = useFormikContext();

  // do what you want with formik
}
```

Comment: I've wrapped everything like you show me and i get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined. It could be because i got it into A modal: `<Modal open={boolean} onClose={onCloseModal}> {body} </Modal>`

Comment: ok, solved it adding `<Modal open={boolean} onClose={onCloseModal}>  <div><Body /></div> </Modal>` but still have problems. Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops. I have to check it

Comment: so how do we implement `useFormikContext()` hook if we're using `useFormik()` hook?

Comment: useFormik is an internal hook used to initialize Formik, and useFormikContext is the hook used to actually use Formik functionality in user code @MekelIlyasa or: useFormikContext() is a custom React hook that will return all Formik state and helpers via React Context and useFormik() is a custom React hook that will return all Formik state and helpers directly. Despite its name, it is not meant for the majority of use cases. Internally, Formik uses useFormik to create the <Formik> component (which renders a React Context Provider).